Multiple instances of Dynamic Reconfigure - Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node
I have two nodelets nodeletA.cpp and nodeletB.cpp. I have to config files nodeletA.cfg and nodeletB.cfg. My package name is dynamic_tutorials and below is my cmakelist
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(dynamic_tutorials)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  dynamic_reconfigure
  roscpp
  rospy
  nodelet
)

generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
  cfg/nodeletA.cfg
  cfg/nodeletB.cfg
)


catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS dynamic_reconfigure roscpp rospy nodelet 
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(dynamic_tutorials
  src/nodeletA.cpp
  src/nodeletB.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(dynamic_tutorials
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_dependencies(dynamic_tutorials ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg)  # Moved this line below add_library

install(FILES nodelets/nodeletA.xml nodelets/nodeletB.xml
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION})


My nodelet.launch file
<launch>

    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="nodelet_manager"  args="manager" output="screen"/>            

    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="nodelet_a"  
            args="load nodeletA/NodeletA nodelet_manager" output="screen">
    </node>

    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="nodelet_b"
            args="load nodeletB/NodeletB nodelet_manager" output="screen">
    </node>
  
</launch>


NodeletA.cfg
#!/usr/bin/env python
PACKAGE = "dynamic_tutorials"

from dynamic_reconfigure.parameter_generator_catkin import *

gen = ParameterGenerator()

gen.add("enable", bool_t, 0, "Enable param", False)

exit(gen.generate(PACKAGE, "nodeleta", "NodeletA"))

NodeletB.cfg
#!/usr/bin/env python
PACKAGE = "dynamic_tutorials"

from dynamic_reconfigure.parameter_generator_catkin import *

gen = ParameterGenerator()

gen.add("enable", bool_t, 0, "Enable param", False)

exit(gen.generate(PACKAGE, "nodeletb", "NodeletB"))

Both cfg files have same param named 'enable'. In my nodeletA.cpp and nodeletB.cpp, I've imported NodeletAConfig.h and NodeletBConfig.h. When I launch the launch file, I get "Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/nodelet_manager/set_parameters]" error and in my rqt_reconfigure gui, I could see only one node named "nodelet_manager" and one param "enable". I need to display two nodelets and each should have param named "enable" If I change the value under one nodelet name, it should trigger a nodelet dynamic reconfigure callback. Please help me
